# Htaccess Rewrite rule for removing a dot

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Thanks for your help. I have been trying to solve this for an hour now.

I had this Htaccess that would rewrite /file.html to a script but decided to remove the extension and it turned out like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, now I need it to work also with filename containing the dot (i.e. /file.with.dots) but that rule doesn't allow it.

This one works for files with dots but ending in .html

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

This gets me an Internal Server Error

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks, Jack, for your quick reply, but the filename with dots are not still working. Before I was getting a Forbidden error but now I am getting 404 for those. The rest of them are working fine.

Comment: Did you try using the above rule except with this rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]` However it should work.

Comment: I tried that one as well, however, I am still getting 404: Status: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  Could it be an issue with the hosting ?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: RewriteEngine On
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]` is there a way to see what is the file showing 404 ? I mean to show where is redirecting to i.e. /index.php?file=XXX  thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help, it turns out it was an issue with the hosting and they removed the restriction. They said: We checked the server log and found that there was a mod security rule
triggered for your domain. This cause the issue you were experiencing. We
installed a mod_security module for increasing the security of our
servers. Its activity may cause such issues from time to time, when
requests sent to the server match with mod_sec rules. Sometimes such
requests are false-positive.

We whitelisted the mod-security rule triggered and it shall not cause
issues any more.

Comment: I see. Well please accept the answer if it helped you. The rules work but the mod_security was the problem.